# remove rows with same id but different value in another column in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

```
id = c("a2887", "a2887", "a5511","a5511","a2806", "a1491", "a1491", "a4309", "a4309") 
plan = c("6V", "6V", "25HS", "50HS", "25HS", "250Mbps", "250Mbps", "15Mbps", "15Mbps") 
df = data.frame(id, plan)
```

It looks like:

```
   id    plan 
a2887      6V
a2887      6V
a5511    25HS
a5511    50HS
a2806    25HS
a1491 250Mbps
a1491 250Mbps
a4309  15Mbps
a4309  15Mbps
```

I'd like to remove rows have same id but with different value in column plan, only keep rows with unique ID/plan match and create a new dataframe looks like:

```
   id    plan
a2887      6V
a2806    25HS
a1491 250Mbps
a4309  15Mbps
```

Is there any elegant way to achieve this?
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`.  After grouping by 'id', `filter` the groups of 'id' having only a single unique value for 'plan' and get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(plan)==1) %>%
   distinct()
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups: id [4]
#  id     plan   
#  <fctr> <fctr> 
#1 a2887  6V     
#2 a2806  25HS   
#3 a1491  250Mbps
#4 a4309  15Mbps
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df <- unique(df)
df[, idx := .N, by = id]
df <- df[!(idx > 1), ]
df[, idx := NULL]

     id    plan
1: a2887      6V
2: a2806    25HS
3: a1491 250Mbps
4: a4309  15Mbps
```

Answer (score 2):

base R solution:

```
# split df into different groups by id after removing duplicates
df <- unique(df)
df <- split(df, df$id)

# keep those 'groups' with only a single row
df <- df[sapply(df, nrow) == 1]

# bind rows together
df <- do.call(rbind, df)
```

Comment: @Gregor You are right. I edited it to remove the duplication.